# The jar netty-tcnative-openssl-static seems to be dynamically linked to the OpenSsl libraries on machine, is this corrrect?

Tags: netty

I have built the artifact, netty-tcnative-openssl-static-2.0.20.Final-linux-x86_64.jar from source.  However I noticed that the libnetty_tcnative.so is dynamically linked to openssl as opposed to being static linked:

```
    [root@omega 2018-12-14--00-24-20 sb are you NRUSSEL? #]ldd META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.so
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.so'
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd42c2000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007febf86b5000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007febf82cf000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007febf80c7000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007febf7e90000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007febf7c72000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007febf78de000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007febf769a000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007febf73b2000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007febf71ae000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007febf6f82000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007febf6d7d000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007febf6b67000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563e43578000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007febf6964000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007febf6758000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007febf6555000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007febf633b000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007febf611b000)
```

Is this correct or do I have an issue with my build process?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah no idea what you are doing but I just did tried it with current master branch of netty-tcnative and it just works:

```
./mvnw -pl openssl-static clean package
```

After this is done you can see all is as expected:

```
[root@d7724df14184 code]# ldd openssl-static/target/native-lib-only/META-INF/native/linux64/libnetty_tcnative.so
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `openssl-static/target/native-lib-only/META-INF/native/linux64/libnetty_tcnative.so'
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcbadb5000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007faccd3b1000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007faccd17a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007facccf5d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007facccd59000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faccc9c5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faccdae9000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007faccc7c2000)
```

You can use the docker-compose file for centos for example to ensure you have the right env environment setup:

```
netty-tcnative git:(master) docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.centos.yaml -f docker/docker-compose.centos-6.18.yaml run shell
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.